# Error while building Ionic Cordova application

Tags: android, maven, cordova, ionic-framework, visual-studio-2015

I am using Ionic Framework with Apache Cordova (6.0.0) in Visual Studio 2015 on Windows 10 to create a mobile app. While building the app behind a corporate proxy the output window shows the following build errors:

> FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
>
> MSBUILD : cordova-build error : * What went wrong:
>    * What went wrong:
>
> MSBUILD : cordova-build error : A problem occurred configuring root project 'android'.
>
> A problem occurred configuring root project 'android'.
>
> MSBUILD : cordova-build error : > Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':classpath'.
>
> Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':classpath'.
>
> Could not resolve com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.5.0.
>   Could not resolve com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.5.0.
>
> MSBUILD : cordova-build error :   Could not GET 'https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/android/tools/build/gradle/1.5.0/gradle-1.5.0.pom'.
>
> MSBUILD : cordova-build error :  > Connection to http://proxy:443 refused

However moving out of the proxy network to an open network still shows the same set of errors while building.

Other information:

1.) I have installed API16 - API24 through SDK manager.

2.) Other dependencies - Java jdk1.8.0, Git v2.10.0 and npm v2.7.4 are also installed in the machine correctly.

3.) Running VS2015 as administrator.

4.) Tried clearing Cordova cache too from `Tools->Options->Tools for Apache Cordova->Clear Cordova Cache`

Comment: Try running cmd as administrator.

Comment: @SwapnilPatwa I am already running Visual Studio as an administrator.

Comment: The same errors appear on doing a cordova build through command line?

Comment: Did you check the `Automatically detect proxy configuration` under `Tools->Options->Tools for apache cordova`. And please also try rm the platform ,clear the cordova cache.

Comment: @ElvisXia-MSFT `Automatically Detect Proxy Configuration` is checked. And yes I did try clearing cordova cache as well as removing platform.

Comment: @Keerthi the setup I am using is primarily Visual Studio Based meaning I installed VS Supported Toolkits for Ionic and Cordova. The same however aren't available on windows cmd by the process and you will have to manually install them by hitting `npm install -g ionic cordova`. Due to some restrictions I am stuck with using it with Visual Studio only.